# play media file or open image in browser cakephp

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am using cakephp 2.x i want to play the audio and open image in a browser ....

In my 'view' I have the following code which is correctly showing the filename, and displaying the download link and the file is successfully downloading

```
 <?php  echo $this->Html->link('Download', array('controller' => 'bugshot', 'action' => 'download', $files['Audio']['filename']));?>
```

now i want to play this audio file as well ..as i have two licks on the page ,,, first is download and tthe other is view or play

In my controller I have the following code that is downloading the file

```
      public function download($filename) {

    $idUser = $this->Auth->user('idUser');
    $folder_url = APP.'uploads/'.$idUser.'/'.$filename;
    $this->response->file($folder_url, array('download' => true, 'name' => $filename));

    return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: To play an audio file you will need some kind of player to make it cross browser compatible. What format is the Audio file?

Comment: @YonoRan i know but at times i just want to view... forexample skip the audipo part .. how can i view an image

Comment: @AD7six  okkk let me try .. sorry for late reply to all ov u

Comment: @AD7six   thankyou ... ur answer solved my problem ... i just did download to false and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Downloading and serving files is almost the same

Serving files via Cake can be done with one function similiar to the following:

```
public function download($filename) {
    $download = !empty($_GET['download']); // <- example

    $idUser = $this->Auth->user('idUser');
    $folder_url = APP.'uploads/'.$idUser.'/'.$filename;
    $this->response->file($folder_url, array('download' => $download, 'name' => $filename));
    return $this->response;
}
```

That way requesting the url `/.../this-file.mp3` will serve the file, whereas the url `/.../this-file.mp3?dowload=1` will download it.

### Audio is a html5 tag

The simplest way to serve audio, is to just use the [audio tag](http://caniuse.com/audio):

```
<?php
    $url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'x', 'action' => 'download', $name));
    $download = Router::url(array('controller' => 'x', 'action' => 'download', $name, '?' => array('download' => 1)));
?>
<audio src="<?= $url; ?>" controls>
<!-- alternate content for unsupported case -->
Download <a href="<?= $download ?>">Download it</a>;
</audio>
```

Being a relatively new tag, support isn't universal - see [Detailed article on support](http://24ways.org/2010/the-state-of-html5-audio/) or other resources for more information on how to handle browsers that do not support this tag.

Or, use one of the many flash based media players that exist.